# When I tried to use PARTITION BY at KSQL, but the field that PARTITION BY use, will missing at the value

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a topic test_partition_key_stream, and it's have the schema like this:
value:             key:null
`{ "id": 1, "age": 18, "name": "lisa" }`
Then I did this:
`CREATE STREAM TEST_STREAM_JSON (id INT ,age INT ,name VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'test_partition_key_stream', VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON');`

`CREATE STREAM TEST_STREAM_AVRO WITH (PARTITIONS=3, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM TEST_STREAM_JSON  PARTITION BY ID;`

But when I use PARTITION BY, the 'ID' field will missed at the topic value side.

The new Topic generated to:
`{ "fields": [ { "default": null, "name": "AGE", "type": [ "null", "int" ] }, { "default": null, "name": "NAME", "type": [ "null", "string" ] } ], "name": "KsqlDataSourceSchema", "namespace": "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas", "type": "record" }`

I want to let the new topic partition by ID, but I don't want to lose it at vaule.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The PARTITION BY clause moves the columns into the key. If you want them in the value also, you must copy them by using the AS_VALUE function.

The doc by https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/partition-data/